# Lambda expression for setter

Tags: java, lambda, setter, getter

We have lambda expression for getter as below:

```
Function<Student, String> studentNameGetter = Student::getName;
```

How about lambda expression for the setter?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by creating a lambda expression for the setter.

What it looks like you are trying to do is to assign the method reference to a suitable Functional Interface. In that case, the best match is to a [`BiConsumer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html):

```
BiConsumer<Student, String> studentNameSetter = Student::setName;
```

Comment: Can you explain why this works? I thought a `BiConsumer<Student, String>` can only be assigned to something like `(Student a, String b) -> a.setName(b)`. But the signature of `setName` has only one parameter.

Comment: @T3rm1 it works because `Student a` is one parameter & `setName` has one parameter. So the consumer takes the target object as well as the setter parameter as its parameters.