# Declare Consumer (Setter) on object not yet created

Tags: java

I have the following code that i want to put into a method to be reused:

```
    List<ClText150> names = attribute.getName().getClText150();
    for (ClText150 clText : names) {
        Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag(clText.getCl());
        AttributeText attributeText = textsMap.get(locale);
        if (attributeText == null) {
            attributeText = createText(locale);
            textsMap.put(locale, attributeText);
        }
        attributeText.setName(clText.getValue());
    }
```

This i need for different lists of ClText150 (an object from a xml). Same code i need for

```
List<ClText150> shortNames = attribute.getShortname().getClText150();
```

But this time caling `setShortname` with the value. The same i need for other fields.
Is there a way to parametrize this setter?

I created a method doing the job:

```
private void handle150(List<ClText150> list, Consumer<String> setter) {
    for (ClText150 clText : list) {
        Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag(clText.getCl());
        AttributeText attributeText = textsMap.get(locale);
        if (attributeText == null) {
            attributeText = createText(locale);
            
        }
        setter.accept(clText.getValue());
        //attributeText.setName(clText.getValue());
    }
}
```

The problem is how to call this method declaring the setter of the object (`attributeText`) that exists only in the method. This is obviously not working:
`handle150(names, AttributeText::setName);`

If not possible what alternatives i have to just copy paste the code?

Comment: reflection? But in my opinion, don't over complicate it.   If you need to call a few setters, please write helper methods instead so that other developers understands what is going on.

Comment: yeah reflection would be too much i think (but yes it would work). what do you mean with helper methods? How they might look?

Comment: I just meant to use your setters as they are, without over complicating it.  If you need to use attributeText.setName() and attributeText.getShortName(), use them...dont try to make it complex and generic

Comment: but the i need to copy the code, i get names, shortnames from different lists

Comment: I might not have understood your requirements exactly, please see the answer.

Comment: Unclear where `textsMap` is defined

Comment: Use `BiConsumer<AttributeText, String>` and then call it like `setter.accept(attributeText, clText.getValue())`.

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer. The setter must be declared as a BiConsumer not a consumer see [Lambda expression for setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759948/lambda-expression-for-setter)

So in my case:

```
private void handle150(List<ClText150> list, BiConsumer<AttributeText, String> setter) {
    for (ClText150 clText : list) {
        Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag(clText.getCl());
        AttributeText attributeText = textsMap.get(locale);
        if (attributeText == null) {
            attributeText = createText(locale);
            
        }
        setter.accept(attributeText, clText.getValue());
    }
}
```

With this i can call with static method reference:

```
        handle150(names, AttributeText::setName);
        handle150(descriptions, AttributeText::setDescription);
        handle150(longNames, AttributeText::setLongName);
        handle150(shortNames, AttributeText::setShortName);
```

why and how this works is explained [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.1).

Answer (score 1):

This is based on my understanding.  I am trying to simplify this.
However if you feel this does answer your question, please tell me and I will remove it.

```
   enum ConsumeOptions{
        NAME, SHORTNAME
    }
```

---

```
    private void handleAttributeText(ConsumeOptions option, AttributeText attributeText, String value){
    
           switch (option) {
                case NAME: 
                         attributeText.setName(value);
                         break;
                case SHORTNAME:
                         attributeText.setShortName(value);
                         break;
    }
```

---

```
private void handle150(List<ClText150> list, ConsumeOptions option) {

    for (ClText150 clText : list) {

        if (attributeText == null) {
            attributeText = createText(locale);
            
        }
           handleAttributeText(ConsumeOptions.NAME, attributeText, "newValue");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks - this might indeed work and it is straight forward. But you brought-up reflection and this works also. And in my case using reflection i can handle also "ClText2000" and all other declared in xml (same methods but different classes.) I'll wait a bit but most likely also accept your answer

Comment: I wont persuade you otherwise.  Just remember to keep it simple for future developers who will maintain your code.